# What is the difference between `importmap` and `importpath` in Bazel **BUILD** file

Tags: go, build, bazel

What different functionalities do these two declarations make in a *Golang* project **Bazel BUILD** file.

example scenario:

```
go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = [
        "etcd.go",
        "strategy.go",
    ],
    importmap = "path_to_package",
    importpath = "path_to_package",
    deps = [
        "//path_to_dependacy:go_default_library",
        "//path_to_dependacy:go_default_library",
        "//path_to_dependacy:go_default_library",
],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

`importpath`

`type: string`

`default: required value`

> The source import path of this library. Other libraries can import
>   this library using this path. This must either be specified in
>   go_library or inherited from one of the libraries in embed.

---

`importmap`

`type: string`

`default: ""`

> The actual import path of this library. This is mostly only visible to
>   the compiler and linker, but it may also be seen in stack traces. This
>   may be set to prevent a binary from linking multiple packages with the
>   same import path e.g., from different vendor directories.

---

Source: [Bazel Docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/core.rst#attributes)

Comment: What do you think could be the cause for **found forbidden imports for _package_name_**. Bazel Build is failing but the app compiles successfully and the imports work just fine.